# Using Self Hosted Video URL With Custom Fields

Tags: post-meta

Can't get this to work with a self hosted video URL added to a custom field.

```
function video() {


$self_hosted           = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'self_hosted', true );

$video_self_hosted     = $self_hosted ? $self_hosted : get_theme_mod( 'customizer-video' ); 

$video_src_url         = wp_get_attachment_url( $video_self_hosted ); 


if ( $video_src_url ) {

        echo '<div class="video-container">';

        $attr = array(
            'src' => $video_src_url,
            'poster'  => $video_thumb,
            'preload' => 'none',
        );

        echo wp_video_shortcode( $attr );
        echo '</div>';

    }

}

get_theme_mod( 'video-upload' ); equals the default video added via the customizer which displays but the URL from the custom field doesn't.
```

If a video URL is added via custom field named *self_hosted* i need to use this instead but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works. This gets the src URL entered into the custom field using get_post_meta and prints the video using [`wp_video_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_video_shortcode)

```
function video() {

$self_hosted = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'self_hosted', true );

$video_src_url = $self_hosted ? $self_hosted : wp_get_attachment_url( get_theme_mod( 'customizer-video' ) );

if ( $video_src_url ) {

        echo '<div class="video-container">';

        $attr = array(
            'src' => $video_src_url,
            'poster'  => $video_thumb,
            'preload' => 'none',
        );

        echo wp_video_shortcode( $attr );
        echo '</div>';

    }

}
```

You can use this code to display a video added via the customizer otherwise a video added via  custom field is shown if present.